# Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject (openweather API)

Tags: java, android, json

Here's my code :

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

            for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("main",jsonPart.getString("main"));
                Log.i("description",jsonPart.getString("description"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    task.execute("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1");
}
```

[image: logcat shot]

This error shows up. It says  Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. But I saw the same code worked for an instructor in Udemy.I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. How do I solve this?
What changes do I need to make in my code?

Comment: try to be as specific as you can in your questions. like on which line is your error occurring.

Comment: I added Logcat shot which contains the error-occurring line, isn't that enough?

Comment: its only saying the line number where the error occurs which one this is we can't really know

Answer (score 0):

weatherInfo must be JSONArray, not String
And then get your String with index 0

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
            JSONObject jsonWeather = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

Comment: Managed to solved it. My code was perfect except the url which caused the error. Changing the url worked for me. Thanks btw.